# HTML/PHP/AJAX/JS/MYSQL | Chat application

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, cordova

I have been searching online to find a simple basic chat application example, i find a lot of them with PHP (index.php) with mysql and ajax. However that is not what i need, i need a simple Peer to Peer and Peer to Group chat source or tutorial links using the below.. index.HTML, PHP on server side, authentication using MYSQL and ajax.

I am not asking for a complete code, may be a reference or any Idea would be great.a refference to any url that meets my requirements. I am particular about HTML is because this simple chat will be on phonegap and phonegap understands only HTML and jS.

It is a HTML chat application, using server side PHP.. a basic chat application example would do...

Answer (score 1):

You might double check what's in the index.php file, as you might be able to easily edit out the php and rename it index.html.

However, if that's not possible, then create the html/css as you want it to look, create an ajax call to a php script that will query for the chat logs - (echo it from the php to return it to ajax) and dynamically add it to the page using js (jquery makes this easier - adding/removing elements to the DOM). A second AJAX call would be to submit a new message, but make sure that you either append the new message to the chat (that's currently visible), or call the function that has your first AJAX call to retrieve the latest chat log from the server.

This should get you started, if you need further help with what the php scripts should be doing then let us know.

Here is a slightly different approach that might help as well, as it was designed for phonegap. http://quickblox.com/developers/XMPP_Chat_Phonegap_Sample

Comment: That was a quick help, i will work on the sample suggested by you and get back  for any help.. cheers

Comment: the XMPP has chat sample for mac, can you suggest a hint for me to use PHP..to connect MYSQLi database

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp ....that's assuming you're just after the php function to connect, in which case this walks you through it...you mentioned it's to a MYSQL DB in which case the generic php functions should work assuming you have the parameters needed (host, db, pwd, etc). If that's not what you needed, could you try to be a little more specific or post code samples (append to the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Use this chat.. Need to just copy and paste the java-script provided

[Zopim live chat](https://www.zopim.com/?lang=en-us)

Comment: Any path/url where i can download the files related to this ?

Comment: No need any files.. just sign-up for free. They provide one java script code and just copy and paste it in your page.. That's all...

Comment: But how does that communicate with my Database users and their authentication on MySQLi ?

Comment: Your will be on the back-end and you will receive messages from user and you have to reply to them. you can block them if it is a spam

Answer (score -1):

Reefer this  url https://subinsb.com/group-chat-in-php-with-ajax-jquery-mysql

let us know  if  need any help.

Comment: this meets all my requirements, but i do not see a index.html. Can you or others suggest any that can fit it for HTML, like P2P and Group. I can take care of PHP connecting to mysqli DB and session and stuff. I need help with a simple example of P2P chat and Group using HTML (PHP on server) Javascript and HTML on client side.